# "using" is not closing Connection

Tags: c#, oracle, connection, bulkinsert, using

This is the code we are using to insert records in Oracle database

```
using (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection conn = 
                new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy c = new 
                  Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy(conn, UseInternalTransaction)
          )
    {
        c.DestinationTableName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Schema, Destination);
        c.WriteToServer(dtLimitStatsDetails);
        c.Close();
    }
}
```

After some time of running this code we started receiving below error

```
ORA-01012: not logged on
```

On inspection we found that there are **~20,000 sessions** with this `ConnectionString` i.e. sessions (connections) are not being closed.

> [The connection is automatically closed at the end of the using
>   block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

It looks '`using`' is not closing Connections, Why?

Comment: That is strange. Try to pass `Connection Lifetime` parameter in your connection string. Or put `conn.Close()` before last `}`

Comment: @Szer I will but why :)

Comment: You code shows an "OracleConnection" but your link shows the documentation of the "SqlConnection", maybe "OracleConnection" behaves differently ?

Comment: @MeAndSomeRandoms apparantly not: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) . same behavior is explained there

Comment: The MSDN link you provided is still for a different class -       System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection - than you are using in your code (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection). I second @MeAndSomeRandoms's guess. Since a `using` block is just an implicit call to `Dispose` when going out of scope, you could use [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to disassemble the Oracle library and have a look yourself.

Comment: "The Close method rolls back any pending transactions. It then releases the connection to the connection pool, or closes the connection if connection pooling is disabled." this could mean that the disposing of the connection does not actually close the connection but releases the connection to the connection pool.

Comment: It is probably connection pooling behaviour as @MeAndSomeRandoms mentioned.

Comment: @MeAndSomeRandoms You mean Pooling is enabled then why am i getting new connections resulting in 20k?

Answer (score 0):

using statement, provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

SqlConnection class has an overriden method which is closing the connection.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if (disposing)
  {
    this._userConnectionOptions = (DbConnectionOptions) null;
    this._poolGroup = (DbConnectionPoolGroup) null;
    this.Close();
  }
  this.DisposeMe(disposing);
  base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

if you're using a custom OracleConnection class, you must implement IDisposable interface and close connection in Dispose method.

if not, close connection manually and check if there is an error.

last advice, unwrap OracleConnection using statement;

```
using (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy c = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy(ConnectionString, UseInternalTransaction))
{
    c.DestinationTableName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Schema, Destination);
    c.WriteToServer(dtLimitStatsDetails);
    c.Close();
}
```